# How to exclude content found within quotation marks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following function, but I do not want it to replace anything within quotation marks when I call it:

```
Function AutoReplace(source As String, typeText As String)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Trim(source)
        .Replacement.Text = typeText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the requirement. Especially since some of the source / typetext examples look identical. Could you clarify some of that and also provide example pairs of what you do / do not want to find? I suspect you could use wildcards...

Comment: Sorry, I just changed that portion of code (and it's not working). I would Call AutoReplace("can't", "cannot"), but I would not want it to replace any word that is within quotation marks. It should not change the "can't" in the following: "I can't write code well."

Comment: I'm currently on a mobile device, so can't do any testing or looking up of wildcard symbols... Are you familiar with Word's Find dialog box? Click "More", acivate the wildcard checkbox then look at the list of Symbols. I'm thinking of something along these lines, to start with: "*can't*." If that works then something can probably be done, although I am concerned about identifying whether two sets of quotes are actually a pair and not end of one and beginning of another... Can you narrow the logic down a bit more?

Comment: @Cindy Open and close quotation marks are separate characters. If I'm working on a paper, then I don't want to change anything that has been quoted from another source.

Comment: Then we need to know what the characters are - the ANSI character number. Select opening / closing quotes and run this from the Immediate Window in the VBA editor: ?ASC(Selection.Text)

Comment: @ Cindy The ANSI codes are 147 and 148  for open and close quotation marks, respectively.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes you should click the "checkmark" to the left of my Answer to indicate that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard search can't handle this, unfortunately, so a code solution is required.

The difficulty with this is determining when the search term is within quotes. And of course the search term could occur multiple times within a set of quotes. I tried to think of all permutations, including whether the term occurs at the beginning / end of the document, but I can't guarantee I caught them all...

The trick to the approach I propose is to compare the *location* in the text of the found term, the previous opening quotes and, if those were found, whether the previous closing quotes follow or precede the opening quotes. If no opening quotes are found, the term is obviously not in quotes. If the closing quotes follow the opening quotes, the term is not in quotes. Otherwise, it's assumed the quotes are in pairs and the term is indeed within quotes.

The coding could be more elegant (fewer nested levels), but I'm not being paid for it, so I leave that up to anyone who wants to use it...

```
Sub FindTermNotInQuotes()
  Dim sTerm As String, sReplacement As String
  Dim sOpenQuote As String, sCloseQuote As String
  Dim rngSearch As word.Range, rngOpenQuote As word.Range
  Dim rngTerm As word.Range, rngCloseQuote As word.Range
  Dim bFound As Boolean, rngFound As word.Range

  sTerm = "can't"
  sReplacement = "cannot"
  sOpenQuote = Chr(147)
  sCloseQuote = Chr(148)
  Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.content
  Set rngFound = ActiveDocument.Range(2)
  Do
    With rngSearch.Find
      'Keep previous location so that we can check
      'If searching the open quote is a previous one
      rngFound.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = sTerm
      .Forward = True
      bFound = .Execute
      If bFound Then
        Set rngOpenQuote = rngSearch.Duplicate
        rngOpenQuote.Start = ActiveDocument.content.Start
        With rngOpenQuote.Find
            .Text = sOpenQuote
            .Forward = False
            If .Execute Then
                If rngOpenQuote.Start < rngFound.Start Then
                    'This quote is in front of the previous "hit"
                    'So we need to check if there's a closing quote
                    Set rngCloseQuote = rngSearch.Duplicate
                    rngCloseQuote.Start = ActiveDocument.content.Start
                    With rngCloseQuote.Find
                        .Text = sCloseQuote
                        .Forward = False
                        If .Execute Then
                            'It's not in a quote
                            If rngCloseQuote.Start > rngOpenQuote.Start Then
                                'If close quote is before open quote
                                'then the term is still within quotes
                                rngSearch.Text = sReplacement
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
      End If
      Set rngFound = rngSearch.Duplicate
      rngSearch.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      rngSearch.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
    End With
  Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been working on it and testing a lot. It doesn't find instances of `sTerm` that come before the first open quote in a document or after the final close quote.

Comment: I have a chain of strings like this: `sTerm = "can't"`, `sReplacement = "cannot"`, `Call NewMacros.FindTermNotInQuotes`. It is safe to assume that all quotation marks occur in pairs (I can run a check before). Can I just check whether there is an open or close quote following `sTerm` to make or not make the change? Also, if there are no quotation marks nothing found after `sTerm`, then the word should be replaced.